# How to OData Service(OData) Bytes array into UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, odata

In my iPhone project,I use Odata Service to get data from SQL Server database from web server and update data to client SQLite database.But I face problem in image.Server return binary array for image and this binary array is convert to NSData object.I want to convert this NSData object to UIImage. I use [UIImage imageWithData:] method but It is not ok for me.How to convert this NSData object into UIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decoding it from Base64 with these classes: 
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html